# Does the following create a new object on every executor for every Row, in spark?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, serialization

I have the following example

```
class Add() { val adding = 2; def getVal = 1 + adding }
val a = List(1,2,3).toDF
a.filter(col("value") === new AddOne().getVal).show()
```

Will this create a new object (AddOne) on every executor for every Row/ data point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will be created only once on the driver.
Here is the simplified code of `===` method

```
  def === (other: Any): Column = {
    val right = Literal.create(other)
    EqualTo(expr, right)
  }
```

Where `expr` is your `col("value")` that will be substituted by an actual value and `right` is a foldable literal.

If you have some doubts use `df.explain(true)` it will help you understand what is going to be executed.
In your case:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter ('value = 3)
+- LocalRelation [value#1]
```

Comment: What about more complex getVaue functions

Comment: It doesn't matter if `getVa`l returns some primitive it will be passed to the `===` method. 
Or your return type should be supported by Spark (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/literals.scala#L52)
Otherwise you will get an exception. 
I think you are confused with `map` method. If you use it there, the answer would be positive